# Why I cannot remove the element of the array of useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the code,

```
import "./styles.css";
import Ank from "./Ank";
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [array, setArray] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")) ?? []
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(array));
  }, [array]);
  const Add = () => {
    setArray((e) => {
      return [...e, one.current.value];
    });
  };
  const deleting = (e) => {
    setArray((e1) => {
      return e1.filter((e2, index) => {
        return index !== e - 1;
      });
    });
  };
  const one = useRef(null);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <div className="align">
          <input ref={one} />
          <br />
          <br />
          <button onClick={Add}>Add</button>
        </div>
        <div className="align">
          {array.map((e, index) => {
            return (
              <Ank key={index} onSelect={deleting} index={index + 1} name={e} />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Please check the function `deleting` in the filter section I am trying to delete the elemt from the `array` using `setarray`.

This is the codesandbox link

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-neumann-b0foos?file=/src/App.js:0-1072

Comment: onSelect = {() => deleting(e)) .. try this

Comment: @SarthakGupta its same as just doing `onSelect={deleting}` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e` is an object having `index` as prop... so its `e.index`

```
const deleting = (e) => {
  setArray((e1) => {
    return e1.filter((e2, index) => {
      return index !== e.index - 1; // here
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Why it would be e.index, isn't e an argument

Comment: you can log `e` and see its value ... its an argument having value as `{index: 1}`

Comment: Its value is the index i want to remove

Comment: why not log and see  .. think of it as `const e = {index: 1}` being passed when selected

Comment: <https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-thunder-wdllc2?file=/src/App.js> please fork so I can remove .. also see the `log` to understand what is `e`

Comment: Yes it is now working, earlier it was not, then I copied your code and then worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change a little in your code.
-------- return index !== e.index - 1;------------
You can take by e.index.
Thank you.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import Ank from "./Ank";
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [array, setArray] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")) ?? []
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(array));
  }, [array]);
  const Add = () => {
    setArray((e) => {
      return [...e, one.current.value];
    });
  };
  const deleting = (e) => {
    setArray((e1) => {
      return e1.filter((e2, index) => {
        return index !== e.index - 1;
      });
    });
  };
  const one = useRef(null);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <div className="align">
          <input ref={one} />
          <br />
          <br />
          <button onClick={Add}>Add</button>
        </div>
        <div className="align">
          {array.map((e, index) => {
            return (
              <Ank key={index} onSelect={deleting} index={index + 1} name={e} />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```